# Refactor code in a pythonic way to get the most popular elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe:

|  | image_file | objects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | image_1.png | [car, car, car, car, car, car, car, bus, car] |
| 1 | image_2.png | [traffic light, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car, car] |
| 2 | image_3.png | [car, traffic light, person, car, car, car, car] |
| 3 | image_4.png | [person, person, car, car, bicycle, car, car] |
| 4 | image_5.png | [car, car, car, car, car, person, car, car, car] |

The objects column is a list with the frequency of the object in the image.

I could obtained the most frequent elements according if there are exactly 3 or less elements in the image with this code:

```
result = []

# Iterate through rows of the dataframe
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Count the frequency of each object in the image
    frequencies = Counter(row['objects'])
    # Sort the frequencies from most to least common
    sorted_frequencies = sorted(frequencies.items(),
                                    key=lambda x: x[1],
                                    reverse=True
                                    )

    # Check if there are less than 3 different objects in the image
    if len(sorted_frequencies) <= 3:
        # If so, append all of the objects to the result list
        result.extend([obj for obj, _ in sorted_frequencies])

frequency_3_most_pop = dict(Counter(result))
```

My concern is that iterrows is not the best option for perform an iteration over a dataframe and I would like to refactor the code to avoid it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible input (`df.to_dict('list')`) and the matching expected output?

Comment: You can post your message to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have lists in `df['objects']`, you can simplify your code:

```
frequency_3_most_pop = dict(Counter(x for l in df['objects']
                                    if len(c:=Counter(l))<=3 for x in c))
```

*NB. requires python 3.8+ due to the walrus (`:=`) operator ([PEP0572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)).*

Output:

```
{'car': 5, 'bus': 1, 'traffic light': 2, 'person': 3, 'bicycle': 1}
```

##### timing

performed on 6k rows

```
# original approach
346 ms ± 49.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Counter generator (this approach)
11.5 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'image_file': ['image_1.png', 'image_2.png', 'image_3.png', 'image_4.png', 'image_5.png'],
                   'objects': [['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'bus', 'car'],
                               ['traffic light', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car'],
                               ['car', 'traffic light', 'person', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car'],
                               ['person', 'person', 'car', 'car', 'bicycle', 'car', 'car'],
                               ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'person', 'car', 'car', 'car']],
                  })
```